# bazel cgo links to incorrect .so file path

Tags: bazel, cgo

I'm using bazel cgo to add dependency on .so file. `lld` on the generated binary file show dependency on
`bazel-out/k8-fastbuild-ST-<some-hash>/bin/_solib_k8/<some-path>/<my-library>.so` which doesn't exist. But `_solib_k8/<some-path>/<my-library>.so` exists, can I make sure that `bazel-out/k8-fastbuild-ST-<some-hash>/bin/` is not prepended or how can I fix this? Thanks!